# Notification - Activity Sequence

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a simple app with two activities: Login Activity and Main Activity.

Normally, the Login Activity sends user data to the Main Activity. However, sometimes I receive notifications which lead directly to the Main Activity. The issue is when I go directly to the Main Activity because I don't have any user data.
Here is a small overview:

> Login Activity --user data--> Main Activity <--**NO user data**-- Notification

What is the best way to deal with this situation?

Comment: Add the user data to your message payload.

Comment: It works, 10x! I guess that's the only way

Comment: Cool. I noticed that you put in answer. But I'll go ahead and add in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, you could put the user details in your message payload, specifically in the `data` payload.

However, you must make sure you are sending sending sensitive data only to the corresponding user. In your sample payload, you are sending the details to a topic, which means all users subscribed to that topic would receive it.

Another workaround I can think of is to send only a specific id, then upon opening the activity, have it fetch the details from your Server. I think this is more secure.

Comment: Sounds fair. However, I subscribe every user only to the topic named after its username so he can receive personal notification. I think that is okay.

Answer (score 0):

As AL. suggested you can send the user (or any other data) in the payload

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
{
  "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
    "user": {
       "id": 1,
        etc...
    }
   }
}
```